# How does this option for the paperclip plugin work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

[This tutorial](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html) I read provides this option:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :default_url => "/:class/:attachment/missing_:style.png"
```

I'm not sure what `/:class/:attachment/missing_:style.png` is. Is that the url location of where your default image is? Why are they symbols? Am I supposed to fill them in with something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default_url` indicates the fallback image that it'll go look for to return if there is no actual attached image.

Much like Rails routing, the symbols are tokens indicating where things are going to be dropped in, so that you can have for instance a small, medium, and large fallback image. See [the RDoc page](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/Interpolations) under "instance methods" for specifically what it'll dropping in in each case.

Comment: ok, but am I supposed to copy it exactly as it looks, or am I supposed to fill in the symbols with what should be there?

Comment: and also where am I supposed to place this default image?

Comment: When you do my_model.photo, all it's really returning is a url, or an img tag with the url in the src attr (haven't used the plugin, so I don't know which). This is basically saying "use this url if you don't have an image", so you'll want to put an image wherever the pattern will match. If you only ever want one default image, great: use :default_url => "/images/fallback.png" and put a fallback.png in public/images/. If you have multiple models, you'll end up doing :default_url => "/images/:class/fallback.png" and public/my_model/fallback.png, one for each of your models. Making more sense?

Comment: That last path should be public/images/my_model/fallback.png; my mistake.

Comment: and let's say you want one of the specific sizes for the default picture, what would you do for that?